# Help understanding behaviour of dateadd(day,datediff(day,7,GETDATE()),0)

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

We are using the below code in the WHERE clause of an sql query to return a date of 7 days ago. However, I don't actually understand how it is working.

```
dateadd(day,datediff(day,7,GETDATE()),0)
```

I've read about the DATEDIFF() and DATEADD() functions but they don't match the above.

For example:

DATEDIFF() should be (interval, date, date), but above it is (interval, number, date).

DATEADD() should be (interval, number, date), but above it just has a 0 for the date.

The thing is, it works. It gives the expected output of 7 days ago.

Can anyone help me understand why and how this is working?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty contorted, for sure!

Dates are stored internally as numbers (the number of days since midnight on 1st Jan 1900). So, casting 7 as a Date would be result in a date of 1900-01-08 00:00:00. As of 23rd August 2020, the difference in days between that date and the current date is 44,057 days. If you cast 44,057 as a Date (using the dateadd() function), you get the date of seven days ago - 16th August 2020.

There are quite a number of ways to achieve the above, but possibly a simpler way of constructing the clause would be the following:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE DateDiff(day,MyDateField,GetDate()) = 6 /* six whole days between then and now */
```

Comment: Thanks Macca. Would the simple way of doing it just be DATEADD(day,-7,GETDATE()) ?

Comment: I've added one of the myriad of possible solutions to this, but you'd need to CAST/CONVERT your DateTimes to Dates in your example to round the days down to midnight of the day in question.